# Replace substring of a string of characters with other characters in awk

Tags: linux, awk, text-processing

I have a file which contains a very long string of characters and I would like to replace a substring of it with Ns. Example:

test
    ABCDABCDABCD

I would like to replace a substring of it with all letters N with awk command and sed, all the characters from index 5 to 8, so the total length of letter N is 4.

Output

```
ABCDNNNNABCD
```

I tried something like this:

```
awk '{ v=substr($0,5,4); sed -i "s/$v/N/g";print substr($0,1,4)""v""substr($0,9,12)}' test
```

however, this command seems to give this output:

```
ABCDABCDABC
```

And no substitution was made

I would like to have in the code the number of the index from where to start the substitution, (here, for example, is 4) and the length number of the substitution ( here also 4), so I can just modify these numbers in case I want to start in another position and for a different length of substitution because in reality, I have a string with thousands of letter and I want to replace hundreds of characters so substitution of pattern does not work in my case

Comment: Tip for asking questions — when you say "this command does not seem[s] to work" you should provide bot the expected output and the _actual_ output, or describe what happens when it fails. Saying just "doesn't work" is uninformative.

Comment: sure, thanks for the tip, I modified a bit

Comment: You are trying to mix 2 independent programs. Sed and awk cannot be used within eachother. Just use awk and write `awk '{print substr($0,1,4) "NNNN" substr($0,9)}'`

Comment: hmm.. I see, I cannot use "NNNN" because in reality as I said my replacement is of 10000 Ns so I have to type 10000 times N

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use `awk` and `sed`?  Seems like you actually want one of:

```
$ echo ABCDABCDABCD | perl -pe 'substr($_,4,4)="NNNN"'
ABCDNNNNABCD
$ echo ABCDABCDABCD | perl -pe 'substr($_,4,4)="N"x4'
ABCDNNNNABCD
```

Comment: yeah that, I tried that on my macbook and it works but when I try on a server via ssh there, there is some problem with perl and I cannot use perl so I was looking for an alternative immediate solution

Comment: oh I found a solution, combining awk with gsub instead

Comment: awk '{ v=substr($0,5,4);gsub("[^0-9.-]", "N", v);print substr($0,1,4)""v""substr($0,9,12)}' test

Comment: I like it!,basically I can select a substring, assign it to a variable and change all the non numeric characters in that variable to N and print the modified string...nice, it came to my mind I can do that because I do not have numeric characters

Answer (score 1):

```
$ echo 'ABCDABCDABCD' |
    awk -v b=5 -v e=8 '{
        t=substr($0,b,e-b+1); gsub(/./,"N",t); print substr($0,1,b-1) t substr($0,e+1)
    }'
ABCDNNNNABCD
```

Answer (score 0):

```
echo ABCDABCDABCD | awk '{$0=gensub(/ABCD/,"NNNN",2)}1'
ABCDNNNNABCD
```